# Increment input field value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the **shortest** way in jQuery (or pure JavaScript) to increment the value of an input field?

For instance

```
<input id="counter" type="hidden" name="counter" value="1">
```

so it changes to

```
<input id="counter" type="hidden" name="counter" value="2">
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
$('#counter').val( function(i, oldval) {
    return parseInt( oldval, 10) + 1;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gkxM/9/)**

**OR**

```
$('#counter').val( function(i, oldval) {
    return ++oldval;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gkxM/8/)**

You can wrap any one of the above code within a function and call that for further increment. For example:

```
function increment() {
    $('#counter').val( function(i, oldval) {
        return ++oldval;
    });
}
```

Now call `increment()` when and where you need.

Answer (score 21):

I think that the shortest way is:

```
$('#counter').get(0).value++
```

or

```
$('#counter').get(0).value--
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
var $input = $('#counter');

$input.val( +$input.val() + 1 );​
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7gkxM/)

Comment: Would you suggest to use your selector over `$("#counter")`, if yes, why? So you don't have to assign an extra id?

Comment: what is the purpose of the + in '+$input.val()'?

Comment: @Mahoni I didn't see that there was an id attr, I updated the answer

Comment: @NathanReed so that it doesn't think I want to do `"1" + 1` which will be `11` , and instead first converts it into a number

Answer (score 8):

No need for jQuery here, instead use pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('counter').value++;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RDMPq/

You can move the increment to a function that accepts dynamic IDs for increased portability:

```
function incrementInput(id){
    document.getElementById(id).value++;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uyuGY/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

**jQuery:**

Setup a function to do this:

```
function incrementVal(selector) {
var $item = selector;
var $curVal = $item.attr("value");
$item.attr("value", parseInt($curVal) + 1 );
}
```

Use it with the click of a button:

```
$("#increment").on("click",function() {
incrementVal($('#counter'));
});
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<input id="counter" type="hidden" name="counter" value="1">
<button id="increment">Increment field</button>
```

Hope that helps.